# Kivy position line based on other widget position

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to draw the orbit groundtrack of the ISS on a map and I think I know how I'll do that once I figure out how to position the line on the map.

To figure out line positioning I'm trying to draw a line from the bottom left of the map to the top right, using the following code (minus extra widgets):

```
#:import kivy kivy
#:import win kivy.core.window
<Orbit_Screen>:
    name: 'orbit'
    FloatLayout:
        id: orbit_layout
        Image:
            id: OrbitMap
            source: 'C:/Users/Sam/PycharmProjects/Mimic-Development/Pi/imgs/orbit/map.jpg'
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.56}
            size: (500,300)
            #size_hint_y: 0.598
            size_hint: (None,None)
            allow_stretch: False
            keep_ratio: True
        Widget:
            id: TDRS10
            col: (1,1,1,1)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
            size_hint: '0.01dp', '0.02dp'
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: self.col
                Ellipse:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                Line:
                    points: (OrbitMap.x,OrbitMap.y,OrbitMap.width,OrbitMap.height)
                    joint: "round"
```

Which produces the following image:
[image]

Can anyone help me understand why the starting x coordinate matches with the map but the y coordinate is below the image and the top right coordinates both fall short? Thanks for any assistance. I really thought I understood widget positioning but I guess not.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: To get your orbit line to be correctly aligned with your orbit map, you will probably need to adjust the line coordinates to account for the position and size of the orbit map.

Comment: @JohnAnderson That's what I'm asking. why is OrbitMap.x correct but OrbitMap.y starting below the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OrbitMap` is scaled and translated to meet your `pos_hint` and `size` specifications from your `kv`. Assuming that your orbit line coordinates are in pixels relative to the original map, then you will need to translate and scale those coordinates to match the scale and translation applied to the map image. I believe you can accomplish that using this in your `kv` for the `Widget` `canvas`:

```
Widget:
    id: TDRS10
    col: (1,1,1,1)
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    size_hint: '0.01dp', '0.02dp'
    canvas:
        PushMatrix:
        Translate:
            xy: (OrbitMap.x + (OrbitMap.width - OrbitMap.norm_image_size[0])/2, OrbitMap.y + (OrbitMap.height - OrbitMap.norm_image_size[1])/2)
        Scale:
            origin: 0,0
            x: OrbitMap.norm_image_size[0] / OrbitMap.texture_size[0] if OrbitMap.texture_size[0] > 0 else 1
            y: OrbitMap.norm_image_size[1] / OrbitMap.texture_size[1] if OrbitMap.texture_size[1] > 0 else 1
        Color:
            rgba: self.col
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Line:    # test diagonal line 1
            points: (0, 0, OrbitMap.texture_size[0], OrbitMap.texture_size[1])
            joint: "round"
        Line:    # test diagonal line 2
            points: (0, OrbitMap.texture_size[1], OrbitMap.texture_size[0], 0)
            joint: "round"
        Line:    # test norizontal line
            points: (0, OrbitMap.texture_size[1]/2, OrbitMap.texture_size[0], OrbitMap.texture_size[1]/2)
            joint: "round"
        Line:    # test vertical line
            points: (OrbitMap.texture_size[0]/2, 0, OrbitMap.texture_size[0]/2, OrbitMap.texture_size[1])
            joint: "round"
        PopMatrix:
```

The above uses the `canvas` `Scale` and `Translate` matrices to convert the line coordinates. I have replaced your orbit line with some test lines to make sure that the scheme works.

Comment: Thanks John! That does exactly what I want. So are OrbitMap.y and OrbitMap.width off because the widget is a different size than the image or something? Do you have any good resources for learning that kind of stuff?

Comment: Yes, you must account for the scale and translation that kivy applies to your map. I'm sure there are many resource for learning about computer graphics and matrices, but I'm not aware of anything specific to this situation (except for the documentation of [Kivy Image](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html) and the [context instructions](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.context_instructions.html)).